# Compiling ros node with cmake and swi-prolog

Tags: ros, compilation, cmake, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to all! I have a ROS node that performs some swi-prolog queries using the pl2cpp library (it comes together with the swi-prolog installation). Now, the problem is that when i have a .cpp file that interacts with prolog in this way, i need to compile it together with the used prolog file with the compilation command swipl-ld

ex.
swipl-ld my_ccp_file.cpp my_prolog_file.pl

this generates the stand alone executable with the cpp and the prolog linked together.
I don't know how and when to call this procedure in the compilation process of a ROS node.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43215/compiling-ros-node-with-cmake-and-swi-prolog/) by [McKracken](https://answers.ros.org/users/3153/mckracken/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-09-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think you are required to use `swipl-ld` if you just want to link against prolog. As far as I know, it's just a wrapper that makes sure the right libraries are included and maybe stores some initial state.

However, on Ubuntu, swi-prolog provides a package-config file that you can use in your CMakeLists.txt. For swi-prolog, something like this should work:

```
include(FindPkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(SWIPL REQUIRED swipl)
include_directories(${SWIPL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${SWIPL_LIBRARY_DIRS})

# ... some other stuff and the definition of your executable target
target_link_libraries(<your target> ${SWIPL_LIBRARIES})
```

If initialization of the prolog kernel does not work properly, the reason could be that your prolog home could not be found since your executable will not contain any saved prolog state. Have a look at the corresponding section in the prolog manual. Sorry for not providing a direct link but this site does not like urls with parenthesis and I'm too lazy to look up the corresponding code. Here the url: [http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(2,'9.6',swi('/doc/Manual/findhome.html'))](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(2,%279.6%27,swi(%27/doc/Manual/findhome.html%27))).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1